# is there a way to do ORM in java without using 3rd party library such as Hibernate?

Tags: java, database

Is there a way to do database ORM in java without using 3rd party library such as Hibernate?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course! Write your own ORM library. Or use a different 3rd party ORM library.

Comment: Well, sure. You could implement the same kind of stuff those 3rd party libraries do, but without using them. After all, those libraries are themselves a way to do ORM without other 3rd party ORM libraries! If you're trying to actually do that, then you'll need to be a lot more specific about any problems you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other alternatives than Hibernate like [Spring JDBC template](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html). You can write your Java mode classes as Object representation for your table entries and then use a RowMapper instance to map columns. For eg -

```
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EMP_ID = ?";
            Employee emp = (Employee)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
                    sql, new Object[] { empId }, new RowMapper() {

                        @Override
                        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                            Employee emp = new Employee();
                            emp.setEmpId(rs.getInt("EMP_ID"));
                        }
                    });
```